# Is there a method so you'd find out which/name of functions that were being called?

Tags: javascript, html, console, load

I am trying to get handy in using Google Development Tools.  Do we have a method to identify which functions (specifically Javascript) are used/required before a successful page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect Element, navigate to each script in the static HTML, open the resource in sources, and put a breakpoint at the beginning of each JavaScript file. Refresh the page, then repeatedly click "step into" until all functions have been called. You can see the call stack and scope for every line of code executed in each resource.